# Integral of the Poisson's kernel: $\int_{\partial \mathbb{R}^n_+} K(x,y)dy = 1$.

Tags: integration, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I know the question is silly, but I have a hard time calculating surface integrals. So here we go:

Let $\mathbb{R}^n_+ = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1},x_n); \ x_n > 0\}$. The Poisson's Kernel is $$K(x,y) = \dfrac{2x_n}{n\alpha(n)}\dfrac{1}{|x-y|^n},$$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}^n_+$ and $y \in \partial \mathbb{R}^n_+$. Evans's PDE book (p. 37- 38) says that with a direct calculation we have
$$\int_{\partial \mathbb{R}^n_+} K(x,y)dy = 1.$$
How do you calculate this integral and arrive at this result? Can anyone help me with the details?

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to define your notations more precisely. But if $\mathbb{R}^n_+ = \{(x_i)_{1\leq i \leq n} \in \mathbb{R}^n,\, x_n > 0\}$, then the "surface integral" is simply $\frac{2x_n}{n\alpha(n)}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}{\frac{dy}{(|x_n|^2+|x_1-y_1|^2+\ldots+|x_{n-1}-y_{n-1}|^2)^{n/2}}}$. I'm not entirely sure how to solve this, but changing variables in $y$ to assume $x=(0,\ldots,0,1)$ and taking polar coordinates afterwards seems like a good start.

Comment: I tried to do it around, but I couldn't develop...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notation: given a vector $x$  I will write $x=(x',x_n)$ where $x'=(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$. Since $\partial \mathbb R^n_+ =\mathbb R^{n-1} \times \{0\} $, \begin{align*}
\int_{\partial \mathbb R^n_+} K(x,y) \, dy &= \frac{2x_n}{n\alpha(n)} \int_{\mathbb R^{n-1}} \frac1{(\vert x'-y'\vert^2+x_n^2)^{\frac{n}2}} \, dy'
\end{align*} Making the change of coordinates $z'=\frac{x'-y'}{x_n}$ gives \begin{align*}
\frac{2x_n}{n\alpha(n)} \int_{\mathbb R^{n-1}} \frac1{(\vert x'-y'\vert^2+x_n^2)^{\frac{n}2}} \, dy' &= \frac{2x_n}{n\alpha(n)} \int_{\mathbb R^{n-1}} \frac{x_n^{n-1}}{x_n^n(\vert z'\vert^2+1)^{\frac{n}2}} \, dz' \\
&= \frac{2}{n\alpha(n)} \int_{\mathbb R^{n-1}} \frac1{(\vert z'\vert^2+1)^{\frac{n}2}} \, dz' 
\end{align*} To calculate this final integral you will need to use polar coordinates in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$. After changing to polar coordinates, let $\tau=\rho^2$ to get \begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb R^{n-1}} \frac1{(\vert z'\vert^2+1)^{\frac{n}2}} \, dz' &= (n-1) \alpha(n-1) \int_0^\infty \frac{\rho^{n-2}}{(\rho^2+1)^{\frac{n}2}} \, d \rho\\
&= \frac12 (n-1) \alpha(n-1) \int_0^\infty \frac{\tau^{\frac{n-3}2}}{(\tau+1)^{\frac{n}2}} \, d \tau .
\end{align*} If you look at "Other identities and formulas" on the [Beta function wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) you will see that $$ \frac12 (n-1) \alpha(n-1) \int_0^\infty \frac{\tau^{\frac{n-3}2}}{(\tau+1)^{\frac{n}2}} \, d \tau  = \frac12 (n-1) \alpha(n-1) \mathrm B \big ( (n-1)/2 , 1/2\big )$$ where $\mathrm B$ is the Beta function. Thus, \begin{align*}
\int_{\partial \mathbb R^n_+} K(x,y) \, dy &=  \frac{(n-1) \alpha(n-1)}{n\alpha(n)} \mathrm B \big ( (n-1)/2 , 1/2\big ) .
\end{align*} Using that $\alpha(n)= \frac{\pi^{\frac{n}2}}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}$, $\mathrm B(x,y) = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ and $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ you can verify that $$ \frac{(n-1) \alpha(n-1)}{n\alpha(n)} \mathrm B \big ( (n-1)/2 , 1/2\big ) =1.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot!